# Select con LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Necesito recuperar el codigo de una division la cual es un string y retornarlo para mostrarlo despues. El codigo que tengo es el siguente pero hay algo que no funciona y no se que es. Alguna sugerencia??

```
    public string DivisionCode()
    {

        DataTable tblCollections = clsFrmGlobals.mySet.Tables[0];
        DataTable tblDivisions = clsFrmGlobals.mySet.Tables[2];

        var query = from col in tblCollections.AsEnumerable()
                    from div in tblDivisions.AsEnumerable()
                    where col.Field<int>("DivisionID") == div.Field<int>("DivisionID")
                    && col.Field<int>("CollectionID") == CollectionID
                    select div.Field<string>("DivisionCode");
        return query.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta agregando el resultado que tienes y el resultado que esperas mediante un ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

En principio tu consulta parece correcta. El problema es lo que haces con el resultado.

En `query` lo que vas a tener después de tu consulta es probablemente un `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, es decir, una colección de filas. A ese resultado tu le aplicas un `ToString`, que lo que hará será devolverte el nombre de la clase del resultado (algo como `IEnumerable...`)

Si lo que quieres hacer es devolver el primer resultado de la consulta, lo que debes hacer es usar [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.linq.enumerable.first(v=vs.110).aspx) (si estás seguro de que va a tener resultados) o [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.110).aspx) (para en caso de no tener resultados que devuelva el valor por defecto).

Resumiendo, en tu método cambia:

```
return query.ToString();
```

por

```
return query.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fue necesario, ademas de la sugerencia de Pikoh, cambiar el orden de la consulta. Finalmente quedo asi:

```
public string DivisionCode()
{            
        var query = from div in clsSilex.tblSXDivision.AsEnumerable()
                        from col in clsSilex.tblSXCollection.AsEnumerable()
                        where col.Field<int>("CollectionID") == CollectionID
                        && col.Field<int>("DivisionID") == div.Field<int>("DivisionID")
                        select div.Field<string>("DivisionCode");

        return query.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
}
```